# Silence Push notifications Not received

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have one app in which i am using `silence-push-notifications`. It is working fine but one of my client complained that he has not receiving the updates which means that he is not receiving the `silence-push-messages`. Can some body guide me what will be the possible reasons on the phone settings side which may be my user has disabled because of which he is not receiving the silence push messages.

I guess my code is okay because everyone else is receiving the updates.

Answer (score 0):

For the Silent push Please make sure about :

1. Silent push will only work on the device having iOS7 and higher.
2. Please make sure that you have set content avail in payload which came from the push notification.   content-available' => '1'
3. background fetch mode should be on for the app.
4. And the ck.pem file should be a working one  :)

please check above things. May that can help you.
Thanks.